# Discrepancy with Hurwitz Zeta function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, special-functions, summation, series-expansion

I've come across an issue while using *Wolfram Mathematica* that I don't quite understand.

Consider the following symbolic computation:

```
Clear[n, y, x];
Sum[1/(n + y)^x, {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

> ```
> HurwitzZeta[x, y]
> ```

However, when I plug in specific values `(x = 1/3, y = 1)` to evaluate the sum:

```
x = 1/3; y = 1; 
Sum[1/(n + y)^x, {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

I get an error message:

> ```
> "Sum::div: Sum does not converge."
> ```

What confuses me is when I compute `HurwitzZeta[1/3, 1] // N`, it successfully returns a numerical value: `-0.97336`.

So, why does the `Sum` function claim the series doesn't converge, but `HurwitzZeta`, which should be equivalent according to *Mathematica*'s own symbolic computation, computes a numerical value without issue? Can anyone shed some light on this discrepancy or at least on what I am missing?

Comment: It prints -0.97336  in the cloud...

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников I mistakenly made a "rejection" of your edit. Someone else can come by an approve it though. It's not rejected yet. Sorry about that. The edit seems fine.  I get `-0.97336`, too.

Comment: @MichaelE2 done! Thanks for leaving a comment about this. it was very helpful

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников By the way, the funny value comes from `NSum[1/(n + y)^x, {n, 0, Infinity}]`.

Answer (score 5):

**HurwitzZeta**

When calculating a sum one can choose an option `GenerateConditions -> True` to get appropriate conditions on parameters for convergence of a series

```
Sum[ 1/(n + y)^x, {n, 0, ∞}, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[ HurwitzZeta[x, y], Re[x] > 1]
> ```

This can be also achieved with `SumConvergence[1/(n + y)^x, n]`.
On the documentation pages it says for it is identical for `Re[y] > 0` to `Zeta`,

```
FunctionExpand[ HurwitzZeta[ 1/3, 1]]
```

> ```
>  Zeta[1/3]
> ```

**Riemann Zeta and Dirichlet Series**

```
Sum[ 1/k^z, { k, 1, ∞}, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

> ```
>  ConditionalExpression[ Zeta[z], Re[z] > 1]
> ```

It is defined to be `Sum[ 1/n^z, {n, 1, ∞}]`  for `Re[z] > 1`,  elswhere such a sum is in general divergent and the function is uniquely defined as an analytic continuation of the function for `Re[z] > 1`.

We can also use a regularization for divergent sums, in this case we find a sum with `Regularization -> "Dirichlet"`,  this kind of sums are called Dirichlet series, see e.g. `DirichletL[1, 1, 1/3]`. Dirichlet regularization can provide a finite sum for obviously divergent series (see also `Zeta[-1]`):

```
Sum[ n, {n, 1, ∞}, Regularization -> "Dirichlet"]
```

> ```
>  -1/12
> ```

`z = 1` is the only singularity of `Zeta[z]`,

```
FunctionDomain[ Zeta[z], z, Complexes]
```

> ```
> -1 + z != 0
> ```

```
Sum[ 1/n^(1/3), {n, 1, ∞}, Regularization -> "Dirichlet"]
N @ %
```

> ```
> Zeta[1/3]
>  -0.97336
> ```

**Analyitic continuation of Zeta for 0 < Re[z] < 1**

We can also express `Zeta[1/3]` in terms of an ordinary series by an  analytic continuation, see e.g. [25.2.3](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.2#info)

```
1/(1 - 2^(1 - z)) Sum[ (-1)^(n - 1)/n^z, {n, 1, ∞}, 
                       GenerateConditions -> True] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[ Zeta[z], Re[z] > 0]
> ```

This is a precise approximation of the series `1/(1 - 2^(2/3)) NSum[(-1)^(n - 1)/n^(1/3), {n, 1, ∞}]` although the convergence is rather slow, e.g. `1/(1 - 2^(2/3)) NSum[(-1)^(n - 1)/n^(1/3), {n, 1, 10^12}]` yields `-0.973275`.

Comment: HurwitzZeta[1/3, 1] // N just prints -0.97336.

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: No problem. I was just confused what 1.082409227768647*10^18635 is.

Comment: That's only an unreasonable edit by JimB. Numerically it yields as you've mentioned.

Comment: Oh, the value was absent before that. Got it.

Comment: Odd that Mma cannot handle the same sum in the form `Sum[1/(1 + n)^(1/3), {n, 0, \[Infinity]}, Regularization -> "Dirichlet"]`.  (+1 for the answer, of course.)

Comment: Digging deep into it, it looks that when x<1, "HurwitzZeta[x, y]" reduces to the analytical continuation of the HurwitzZeta holding when x >1. This seems to be the cause of the initial problem, as when x = 1/3, "HurwitzZeta[x, y]" reduces to that analytical continuation that I have not quite grasped