# How is the analytical continuation for the HurwitzZeta function implemented?

Tags: special-functions, implementation-details

Following up on [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287527/discrepancy-with-hurwitz-zeta-function), I am trying to understand the implementation details of the `HurwitzZeta[x,y]` function in Mathematica, particularly when the first parameter is less than 1. According to the classical definition of the Hurwitz Zeta function, it should diverge for arguments where the first parameter is less than 1. Yet, when I use Mathematica to evaluate expressions like `HurwitzZeta[1/3, 1] // N`, I get a finite, well-defined value (in this case, "-0.97336").

I have consulted Wolfram's MathWorld page on the Hurwitz Zeta function,(https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html, and it's clear that Mathematica uses an **analytic continuation to Hurwitz Zeta** to compute these values. However, the specific method used for this continuation is not explained.

Can anyone provide insight into the specific formulae that Mathematica uses to compute these values?

Comment: `HurwitzZeta` is defined with the help of `Zeta` and an example of series of `Zeta[z]` for `0 < Re[z] < 1`  representing the unique analytic continuation from `Re[z] > 1` I included in my answer.  There are infinitely many series reperesentations of `Zeta`, they depend on the initial point and the radius of convergence.  Wolfram documentation doesn't inform about specific choice of implementation, you can't get more information besides e.g. tutorial on [Mathematical Functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MathematicalFunctions.html#21909).

Comment: For the rest of the complex plane (`Re[z] < 0`)  the system uses also the functional equation $\zeta(s) = 2^s \pi^{s-1}\ \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\ \Gamma(1-s)\ \zeta(1-s)$.